# Dual hover-effects for nested list items in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get different hover effects for list items.

My list is image and title (both being pulled from wordpress) - I want the background box for the title to change color on hover (parent Li) and an effect applied to the image (I've used opacity in the js fiddle example).

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabs999/fzUbt/)

```
<li id="item" class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/></a>
          <br />
        <a href="#" class="p_title">Entry 6</a>
</li>
```

Situation 1: Hover over the image, everything works as I would like it too.

Situation 2: Hover over the black box only, and you get a different effect.

**I would like Situation 2 result = Situation 1 result.**

I've looked at the following on Stack overflow, but no luck.
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410324/menu-item-hover-state-when-not-hovering-jsfiddle-link-included?rq=1)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817575/css-hover-parentchild-items)
[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606905/applying-opacity-to-a-nested-list-item-for-a-fade-effect-using-css3)
[link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675923/hover-on-nested-item-can-affect-its-parent)

Please help!
I thought it was my markup, but I've changed it a few times and that didn't fix it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. I was set on CSS-only, but if java script fixes it, then that's great too.

Thanks

Fabs

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare the :hover on the li and then select the img or the title after that. Also, your markup could be a bit better. For example:

```
<li class="item">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    <br />
    <span class="p_title">Entry 6</span>
  </a>
</li>

li.item:hover img {
  opacity: 1; }

li.item:hover {
  background-color: #fb8008; }
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Coop, that seems to work exactly how I intended it! I corrected the markup as you suggested and added your style suggestions.Also thanks to cchana for editing my post. For anyone who comes across the same issue, here's the corrected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabs999/aZbef/)